# android : web view does not resize on on screen keyboard pop up

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using phonegap and jquery mobile. my application is not resizing on onscreen popup  I have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  and adding a preference full screen and setting it's value to false but none worked for me . am i missing anything .. is there any other solution .

Comment: where did you try to put the fullscreen preference?

Comment: on cordova.xml in the res folder

Comment: it should be in config.xml (either at root of project or in www folder, depending of version of cordova you're using) `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`

Comment: i don't have a config.xml . do i need it .. i have a cordova.xml instead in res folder

Comment: So you don't use the CLI? Maybe you're using cordova 2.x?

Comment: i am using cordova 1.9.0 and yes i don't use cli ..